# Issue with static method in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, static

I have an issue with the static method in ASP.NET. I created the Singleton below. During the execution process I will call Context.getInstance() several times and I need the same context value. But, once I make another request (Get, Post, wherever) to the server I need a new context because my context is dependant from .NET HttpContext. But, unfortunately  once I call getInstance for the first time the class never will be instantiated again.

Any ideas how I solve this problem?

```
public class Context
{
   private static Context _context = null;

   private Context()
   { ... }

   public static Context getInstance()
   {
       if (Context._context == null)
           _context = new Context();

       return _context;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of your static variable and store it in `HttpContext.Current.Items`.

```
public static Context GetInstance()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Items["MyContext"] == null) 
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items["MyContext"] = new Context();
    }
    return (Context)HttpContext.Current.Items["MyContext"];
}
```

Comment: This would be the best way to go.

Comment: Add (Context) in the return statement.

Comment: I implemented this code in my project and seems work. So, every new request I do this HttpContext.Items will start again and it is not shared with another requests, right? If yes, this answer my question.

Comment: @Joao Gilberto, pretty much yes, every new request gets a new `HttpContext.Items` collection.  One exception is if you do a `Server.Transfer` then the continuation will share the same `HttpContext.Items` but then it's also debatable whether or not it is considered a new request or the continuation of the same request.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need the context only in a single page request, correct? 
If so, the method above certainly won't work - the static will live for the life of the app domain. This lifetime can vary depending on a number of factors. 
I would start by creating a base page class (inheriting from the core ASP.NET Page class) and include a Context property on it. Since the page only "lives" for one request, that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach - I prefer using my own ThreadStatic variables (ala HttpContext.Current) rather than use the HttpContext Items collections simply because I think (an opinion) that it makes for cleaner code. YMMV.

```
public class Context
{
    [ThreadStatic()]
    private static Context _Context = null;

    private HttpContext _HttpContext = null;

    public Context()
    {
        _HttpContext = HttpContext.Current;
    }

    public static Context Current
    {
        if(_Context == null || 
           _HttpContext != _HttpContext.Current)
        {
            _Context = new Context();
        }
        return _Context;
    }
}
```

Comment: ThreadStatic is **NOT SAFE IN ASP.NET**.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ATaleOfTwoTechniquesTheThreadStaticAttributeAndSystemWebHttpContextCurrentItems.aspx  Besides that, you cannot access non-static `_HttpContext` within `static` property `Current`.

Comment: I tested your code and looks like it works. But I have a concern about security issues. My context never can be shared with another request and I read on several places this is not safe in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

if your variable is static then all user will access that same variable and any change to that variable will effect all users in case of web-application only, the logic is when your are making a variable static then a memory location is allocated in server when this location is allocated all users share that location only because it is static.